# Why I'm getting out of the loop?

Tags: python, loops

Hello all genius fellows, please find below code. code is running excellent till end but in the end while it ask for Y/N after 1st iteration no matter what I press its breaking the statement and exiting the loop.

```
 class simpleCalculator:
    def addition(self, num1, num2):
        return num1+num2

    def sub(self, num1, num2):
        return num1-num2

    def multiplication(self, num1, num2):
        return num1*num2

    def division(self, num1, num2):
        return num1/num2


a = simpleCalculator()

print("Enter your choice: ")
print('''         1.Addition
         2.Subtraction
         3.Multiplication
         4.Division''')

while True:
    choice = int(input("Enter your choice(1/2/3/4): "))
    if choice in (1, 2, 3, 4):
        num1 = int(input("Enter 1st number: "))
        num2 = int(input("Enter 2nd number: "))

        if choice == 1:
            print(f"Addition of {num1} & {num2} is {a.addition(num1,num2)}")
        elif choice == 2:
            print(f"Subtraction of {num1} & {num2} is {a.sub(num1,num2)}")
        elif choice == 3:
            print(
                f"Multiplication of {num1} & {num2} is {a.multiplication(num1,num2)}")
        elif choice == 4:
            print(f"Division of {num1} & {num2} is {a.division(num1,num2)}")
        next_cal = input("You want more calculation(Y/N): ")
        if next_cal == "N" or "n":
            print("****** Thank you for using world's best calculator ******")
            break
    
    else:
        print("Invalid Choice")
```

Comment: Because the `"n"` in `or "n"` is truthy...

Comment: You need `if next_cal in "Nn"` or `if next_cal.lower() == 'n'`.

Answer (score 0):

class simpleCalculator:
def addition(self, num1, num2):
return num1+num2

```
def sub(self, num1, num2):
    return num1-num2

def multiplication(self, num1, num2):
    return num1*num2

def division(self, num1, num2):
    return num1/num2
```

a = simpleCalculator()

print("Enter your choice: ")
print("1.Addition \n 2.Subtraction \n 3.Multiplication \n 4.Division")

while True:
choice = int(input("Enter your choice(1/2/3/4): "))
if choice in (1, 2, 3, 4):
num1 = int(input("Enter 1st number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter 2nd number: "))

```
    if choice == 1:
        print(f"Addition of {num1} & {num2} is {a.addition(num1,num2)}")
    elif choice == 2:
        print(f"Subtraction of {num1} & {num2} is {a.sub(num1,num2)}")
    elif choice == 3:
        print(
            f"Multiplication of {num1} & {num2} is {a.multiplication(num1,num2)}")
    elif choice == 4:
        print(f"Division of {num1} & {num2} is {a.division(num1,num2)}")
    next_cal = input("You want more calculation(Y/N): ")
    if next_cal == "N" or "n":
        print("****** Thank you for using world's best calculator ******")
       

else:
    print("Invalid Choice")
```